# Difference between flex: 0 0 100% and flex: 1 1 100%

Tags: flexbox

I've tested the following but im asking, just in case there is a difference.

I have a container that is a `flex` container. The items have a property of `flex: 1 1 100%`. Just for curiosity purposes, I've also tested `flex: 0 0 100%` and I haven't notice any difference (maybe there is).

My question is: If the `flex-basis` is a 100%, does it even matter what the other 2 properties values are?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If the flex-basis is a 100%, does it even matter what the other 2
>   properties values are?

Yes. When the width of the items in a flexbox meet or exceed the width of the flexbox itself, `flex-shrink` comes into play (`flex-grow` only applies when the items are less than the width of the flexbox):

For example, in the case below, flex-shrink is set to 0 for the second item, so the second will not shrink, and will take up 100% of the viewport.

```css
.flexbox{display:flex}
.item1,.item2{height:60px}
.item1{flex:1 1 100%;background-color:lightblue}
.item2{flex:0 0 100%;background-color:goldenrod}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
    <div class="item1"></div>
    <div class="item2"></div>
</div>
```

If both items are set to `flex-shrink:1`, they will both take up half of the viewport (they shrink equally to 50%):

```css
.flexbox{display:flex}
.item1,.item2{height:60px}
.item1{flex:1 1 100%;background-color:lightblue}
.item2{flex:0 1 100%;background-color:goldenrod}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
    <div class="item1"></div>
    <div class="item2"></div>
</div>
```

If both are items set to `flex-shrink:0`, neither will shrink and they will both take up 100% of the viewport width, growing the width of the flexbox to twice that of the viewport:

```css
.flexbox{display:flex}
.item1,.item2{height:60px}
.item1{flex:1 0 100%;background-color:lightblue}
.item2{flex:0 0 100%;background-color:goldenrod}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
    <div class="item1"></div>
    <div class="item2"></div>
</div>
```